# Метка "v{с русская}++"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, замена-меток

Есть метка [vс++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/v%d1%81%2b%2b) (с русской `с`), и на ней есть сотня вопросов.
Давайте что-нибудь с этим сделаем, может сделаем ее синонимом нормальной метки [vc++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vc%2b%2b).

Если вы поддерживаете синонимизацию, то проголосуйте за нее [на странице метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-c%2B%2B/synonyms).

Comment: Уничтожить, расстрелять тупой пилой об стенку!

Comment: Надо же было додуматься такую метку сделать.

Comment: Мне кажется, или никто не голосует за синонимизацию? Похоже, метка [meta-tag:status-completed] сбивает с толку.

Comment: И правда. Проголосовал.

Comment: пинганул голосующих участников в чате, но этого недостаточно будет.